# Maximum Value of a Floor-y Function

Tags: number-theory, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $x$ is an integer, find the maximum value of 
$$f(x)=x-\left(\lfloor r_1x\rfloor+\lfloor r_2x\rfloor+\lfloor r_3x\rfloor+...+\lfloor r_{n-2}x\rfloor+\lfloor r_{n-1}x\rfloor+\lfloor r_nx\rfloor\right)$$
Given that $\sum r_i = 1$, where $r_i \in \mathbb{Q} \space\forall i$.

---

So, first I applied the identity of 
$\lfloor r_ix\rfloor = r_ix - \{r_ix\}$
$$f(x)=x-\left(x\left(\sum r_i\right) - \left(\sum   \{r_ix\}\right)\right)$$
And since $r_i$ sums to $1$, all we need to do is find the maximum value of
$$f(x) =\sum   \{r_ix\}$$
But $\{r_ix\} \in [0,1)$, and since we are summing from $i=1$ to $n$, and thus, there are $n$ terms in the sum, I'm tempted to say the maximum is $n-1$. A maximum value of $n$ would imply the upper bound on the fractional function is closed. Is that accurate?

Comment: Can the $r_i$s be irrational?

Comment: @ErickWong, I forgot to stipulate that $r_i$ are rationals. Sorry, I'll fix the question!

Comment: Thanks, you should also add that $r_i \ge 0$ which you use later on but isn't specified by the question.  Also, the question is phrased a bit oddly: $x$ is given, and you are asking for the max value of $f(x)$ which depends on $r_i$.  It sounds like you are more interested in the case where the $r_i$ are given and you have the freedom to choose $x$ to maximize $f(x)$.  Finally, I suspect you mean $x \in \mathbb N$ else this problem is a lot easier...

Comment: Yes, I believe this question was created with the intent of choosing an $x$ to maximize $f(x)$, but the problem specified only that $x \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Note that $f(-1) = n-1$ (assuming that $r_i > 0$).

Answer (score 1):

Trivially, $f(-1) = n-1$ provided all of the $r_i$ are non-zero.  If $n=1$ this is obvious since $r_1 = 1$, and if $n>1$ then $0 < r_i < 1$ so $\lfloor -r_i \rfloor = 0$.  This holds even for positive real $r_i$.  When the $r_i$ are rational, then one can find a positive integer $x$ such that $f(x) = f(-1)$.